# resize stage in Adobe AIR windows application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm realizing an app that runs on a single display in HD and in another setup on two screens. I'm using the none flag to make windows without borders.

Ok, how can I change my fla size after loading the my settings, in authoring the stage size is 3840x1080. how can I get 1920 width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using AIR, you can control this via the [NativeWindow.bounds](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#bounds) property. You may need to add an event listener to the stage so that you don't access its window before activation (i.e. `stage.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, onActivate);`) and then add the following:

```
stage.nativeWindow.bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
[or]
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow.bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

Note that if you do have any system chrome, there will be a difference between the stage size and the window size: you can always take the existing values and do some quick maths to work out how much space is used by the titlebar/borders and adjust your new rectangle appropriately.

Comment: did not work for me, after loading a json file I switch between three setup. one, two or three screens. I get always the size from the animate property window from the fla file. I am using systemchrom none to span the window over multiple screens.